# How can integrate elastic-search with CodeIgniter 3?

Tags: elasticsearch, codeigniter-3

Explain Flow of elastic-search with docker and why use google cloud for them
How to Import data in elasticsearch and manage with codelgniter ?

Comment: Could you please state if you have researched/tried anything yourself.

Comment: yes i researched for elastic search with docker and install on mac with composer they have lots of dependencies during elastic search but i install it and running in localhost:9200 port address and its work as database export and import data are in json format . but i not understand to manage elastic-search and integreate with CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

Find a library for!

Go here : https://packagist.org/?q=elasticsearch&idx=packagist&p=0

You could use official Elasticsearch php client:

`composer require elasticsearch/elasticsearch`

Then follow documentation to create your own service that use the Elasticsearch client.